# Probability of Fog

Tags: probability

I have successfully figured out two previous questions that asked to calculate the expected utility of choosing the train and plane individually, but I just can't figure this one out. I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Information:
"As far as cost and safety are concerned, a train and plane provide equally good ways of traveling from Point A to Point B. The trip takes 8 hours by train and 3 hours by plane, unless the airport at Point B is fogged in, in which case the plane trip would take 15 hours. According to the weather forecast, there is a 70% chance that Point B will be fogged in." Assume that a 1 hour trip has a -1 utility, etc.

Question:
For plane and train to be equally good choices, what would the probability of fog have to be?

What I Know:
Pr(fog) = p
Pr(no fog) = 1-p
Exp(U(train)) = Exp(U(plane))

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the time it takes by train. Let $Y$ be the time is takes by plane.

We wish for

$$E(X)=E(Y)$$

or

$$8=15\cdot P(\text{fog})+3\cdot(1-P(\text{fog}))$$

Solve for $P(\text{fog})$